# tortoise svn branch from working directory

Tags: tortoisesvn

I forgot to take branch of my working directory before starting to make whole lot of changes to the project (trunk). I am half way through and want to create a branch which will include all of my changes that I am working on. Is there a better way with svn?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is switch command sufficient for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- select Branch/Tag on your working copy.
- Fill out info as normal
- Select 'Working Copy' under 'Create copy in the repository from'
- Select 'Switch working copy to new branch/tag' at the bottom

Comment: Thanks. It's better to confirm before doing something where you are not confident. It's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: No problem. That's not something you want to stuff up :)