# Branch from working copy and include non-versioned files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, working-copy

Sometimes I start making changes to my working copy and realize I want to park them in a branch so I can head in a different direction but still have access to the changes if needed.  That's fine, I know how to do that, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697657/2704659.  However, what I can't figure out is how to get the non-versioned files to be included in the branch.  I may have created a few classes that I want as part of the branch.  Is that possible somehow?

Here's the branch UI with nowhere to indicate that.

[image]

Comment: You can't just `svn add` them to the new branch? It won't branch the non-versioned files by default, you would have to add them to the project. Once you svn add them, then it's just a simple `svn commit` to the branch and you should be good to go! And they will still be absent from the trunk since you've only committed them to the branch.

Comment: Works perfectly!  I've never used add because it does that automatically when I'm committing.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help man, I'm move my comment to an answer that others can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you're making a branch from a working copy, it will only branch the currently versioned files -- which is by design to avoid including unnecessary build directories/binaries in your repository.

To add these additional classes, you will just need to move the files to your new branch, perform an `svn add` on the files at hand, then an `svn commit`.

I can definitely see how you could miss the svn add step if you're used to using the SVN commit dialog. I used to do the same thing but then I eventually guided my team to turn that "show non-versioned files" checkbox off so that way the commit log screen isn't cluttered with files I don't care about, and that I'm ***sure*** files I'm committing are the files I want to commit. So `svn add` > `svn commit` is sort of a two-step verification.